# Defining accent characters in different platforms under java

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a problem with the accent character in different platforms.

When I log this in my machine under **fedora** (where default charset is UTF-8) it is printing correvtly as **Sacré Coeur.**

But when i update to another server that is running on **RedHat** (where default charset is ISO-8859-1), it is printing as
**SacrÃ© Coeur.** 
I want to log it in RedHat server as same as in my my Fedora machine. How can I do this?

**My Workout :**

- I tried to changes the System.setProperty("file.encoding",
  "ISO-8859-1"); in local with the purpouse of doing the reverse
  version System.setProperty("file.encoding", "UTF-8"); in the RedHat
  Server, if it change the way of logging in the local. But nothing
  changed.
- I noticed there are couple of threads regarding the accent character
  but nithing answers me. That's why I asked a new question.
- I tried [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding/623036#623036) as well but not working.

  `System.setProperty("file.encoding","ISO-8859-1");
     Field charset =Charset.class.getDeclaredField("defaultCharset");
     charset.setAccessible(true); 
     charset.set(null,null);`
- But I didn't try to set the charset at the JVM start. If it will works please explain me how can I do it?

Comment: What library are you using to log the information? Is it plain `System.out.println()`?

Comment: When you say "it is printing", what environment are you talking about? Desktop? Pages served by a web server? Swing?

Comment: @ asgs, @ T.J. Crowder  : For quicke testing I used sysouts. but in the serever I'm using org.apache.Logger. In both there are not working. And I log the results as XML files. I want to change the XML logging as well

Comment: Have you read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361975/setting-the-default-java-character-encoding?

Comment: @Perception :yep I have referenced it in my question(I tried this one as well but not working.) this one refers to the link. But I didn't try to set the charset at the JVM start. If it will works please explain me how can I do it?

Comment: @NamalFernando - you can specify additional properties for the JVM via the -D argument. Eg: `java -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 MyClass`

Comment: @Perception : Thanx. I tried it with eclipse vm argument setting. It works as you mentioned.+1ed :). I'm building my jar files using ANT. and server is jetty. How to set these arguments relevant to them?

Comment: @NamalFernando - code wont fit in comments, but you can read about how to set Java system properties for Ant [here](http://ideoplex.com/id/372/setting-java-system-properties-with-ant).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get similar out put from all the environments, with out depending on the server OS 
default character encoding, when you start your program or the server environment (Jboss tomcat or jetty) pass -Dfile.encoding to the start-up script

(lets say run.sh in jboss, add -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 to JAVA_OPTS)

-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8